# gitlab and branch with specific access roles

Tags: git, gitlab

Is it possible to restrict access to specific branches in gitlab?

I want to have one repository with different branches and restrict access to specific users for specific branches

e.g. 
master viewable by all, while develop branch viewable only by developers

is this possible, and how?

Comment: Related request (not the same): http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6625487-add-protected-branch-granular-push-merge-permissio

Answer (score 7):

The GitLab protection model is described in "[Keeping your code protected](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/)".

It includes branch protection (as illustrated by [this commit](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/226819c8d171d3fd6f4c5d87649b460d84de6fa9))

> A protected branch does three simple things:
>
> - it prevents pushes from everybody except users with Master permission
> - it prevents anyone from force pushing to the branch
> - it prevents anyone from deleting the branch
>
> You can make any branch a protected branch.
>   **We make the `master` branch a protected branch by default**, but you can turn that off.

Note that this is about read/write, not "visible/invisible": you can still clone the full repo and access read everything.

---

Sure enough, the [OP tbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422807/tbo) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378895/gitlab-and-branch-with-specific-access-roles/27378975#comment43208207_27378975):

> I need to find a way to restrict visibility for specific branch for specific users

That is not how a Git repo works: If you have access to it, you can see all its content (through a clone).
If you have a content which must be invisible, then export it in its own git repo (which you can protect against access).
The first main repo can reference the second more private git repo as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

You can protect a branch against write (but *not* against read)

You can protect a repo against read (through teams).

Comment: Thanks for your comment VonC. I need to find a way to restrict visibility for specific branch for specific users

Comment: @tbo I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: @VonC I think you still haven't answered the question: how to give the access to the **specific** users. I think that it is impossible using GitLab.

Comment: @nme What version are you currently using? A lot has changed since this old answer.

Comment: @nme And are you talking about read access? (aka branch visibility), which does not exists in git, or about write access? (aka branch push) which does exist (although I need to check if that exists for a specific user)

Comment: If something is not possible using git it doesn't imply that it is not possible using GitLab.

Comment: @VonC did you find something regarding **write** access for certain users for a single branch?

Comment: @taclight No I did not. I only saw that with gitolite.

Comment: @VonC Can I use both in conjunction?

Comment: @taclight normally no: GitLab in its old day (pre 5.x version) was based on gitolite. They are not anymore.

Comment: @VonC So if I use the permission settings availabe in GitLab is it only for GitLab or does it restrict force push through the command line as well?

Comment: @tac It should be enforced with command line as well, as long as your are pushing to the same gitlab server.

Comment: @VonC I'm new to hosting/servers...can you elaborate a little more what you mean with "same" server? Does that mean after I set up GitLab I can either access GitLab or Git itself? Don't I still have only one address? It should operate on the same instance no?

Comment: @taclight GitLab manages the access to the git repo, so a git push will be managed by GitLab. You will operate on the same instance indeed.

Comment: @VonC Well I dont get how exactly you are pushing, like what url do I have to provide? Does GitLab give me another address?

Comment: @taclight standard gitlab url (http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/command-line-commands.html): `https://yourgitlab/<user or group>/<yourrepo.git>`

Comment: @VonC I mean hosting on my own server

Comment: @taclight same deal, same url.